# Dynamic validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

So I have a table with dynamic fields communication_type_id and communication_value. If user selects communication_type_id = 4 then communication_value should be phone number which is required and numeric if user select 
Communication_type_id =7 then communication_value should be required and email.How do I do this? I have done following till now but it does not seem to be checking the condition as I get "communication_value must be a valid email address" for both conditions:

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'client_addresses.*.address'=>'required',
        'client_addresses.*.city'=>'required',
        'client_addresses.*.state_province'=>'required',
        'client_addresses.*.country'=>'required',
        //Communication|
        'client_communications.*.communication_type_id'=>'required|numeric',

        //tag
        'tags.*.tag_id'=>'required',

    ]);

          foreach ($request->client_communications as $key=>$com) {
           // dd($com);
               if($com['communication_type_id']== "5")
               {

                 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'client_communications.'.$key.'.communication_value' => 'required|numeric',
                 ]);
               }
               if ($com['communication_type_id'] == "7"){
                  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                 'client_communications.'.$key.'.communication_value' => 'required|email',
              ]);
          }


          }



      if ($validator->fails()) {

       return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
       }
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://themsaid.com/laravel-advanced-validation-conditionally-adding-rules-20170110) can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with getting posted data by $request variable, like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',

    //address

    'client_addresses.*.address'=>'required',
    'client_addresses.*.city'=>'required',
    'client_addresses.*.state_province'=>'required',
    'client_addresses.*.country'=>'required',

  'client_communications.*.communication_type_id'=>'required|numeric',

   //client tag

    'tags.*.tag_id'=>'required',

]);

if($request->communication_type_id == "4"){
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'client_communications.*.communication_value' => 'required|numeric|phone',
 ]);
}

if($request->communication_type_id == "7"){
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'client_communications.*.communication_value' => 'required|email',
 ]);
}

if ($validator->fails()) {
 return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
}
```

If some other solution from laravel validation is appreciated otherwise this approach should well .

Comment: If it helps then do not forget to mark as right answer with upvote.

Comment: in your example $validator gets overridden for example, if user enters alphabets instead of numeric in first condition and enters proper email addresss in second condition, there wont be fail response.

Comment: I think no its not,
First it checks only `communication_type_id` valdation,
then it checks for its value and as per value it checks further validation. :)

Comment: Please have a looks at my edited code right now, what am i doing wrong? because that is what happens from this code

Comment: What are you getting in this `dd($com);` and `dd($com)`?? 
and whats wrong with my code ?
m just taking value of that and check with simple if condition

Comment: dd($com) gets
array:5 [
  "id" => 565
  "communication_type_id" => "5"
  "communication_value" => "7687687687"
  "primary" => "0"
  "created_userid" => "1"
]
This is what happens from aboave code: If users enters wrong data in both cases.Fail response for the only the last case is displayed.

Comment: hmm so thats y u used foreach

Comment: print it `$com['communication_type_id']` before you pass it to condition.

Comment: did u mean dd?
dd($request->client_communications)   gives:
 array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 565
    "communication_type_id" => "5"
    "communication_value" => "79879"
    "primary" => "0"
    "created_userid" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 566
    "communication_type_id" => "7"
    "communication_value" => "abc@yty.com"
    "primary" => "0"
    "created_userid" => "1"
  ]
]
dd($com['communication_type_id']);gives "5"

Comment: nop i had told `echo $com['communication_type_id'];` , before passing it to condition

Comment: did it after foreach and before if condition, same thing happened

Comment: do after foreach and before the condition

Comment: That is what I did

Comment: oh then what is the output?

Comment: same as above. if user enters alphabet in phone(communication_type_id=5) and non-email data in email(communication_type_id=7).only fail response for email is displayed instead of both. If user enters wrong data type for phone but correct for email, there is no fail response and data is saved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158066/discussion-between-user3810794-and-rits).